# Debug segfault race condition

Tags: linux, debugging, segmentation-fault

I can provoke a race condition that gives output similar to this in `dmesg`:

```
[ 5432.541379] perl[408327]: segfault at 22 ip 0000564eb8af9cc2 sp 00007ffec318cea0 error 6 in perl[564eb8af7000+1a1000]
[ 5432.541402] Code: 83 f8 05 0f 87 cf 00 00 00 0f b7 6b 22 66 81 fd 00 04 77 64 01 ed 8d 7d 05 48 63 ff 48 c1 e7 03 be 01 00 00 00 e8 4e ef ff ff <66> 89 68 22 48 89 c3 66 89 68 24 4c 89 68 08 49 8b 45 00 48 89 03
[ 5432.541638] Core dump to |/usr/share/apport/apport pipe failed
[ 5432.660093] perl[408400]: segfault at 22 ip 00005654e7ec3cc2 sp 00007ffe47312cc0 error 6
[ 5432.660106] perl[408415]: segfault at 22 ip 000055b15d088cc2 sp 00007ffe67124210 error 6
[ 5432.660119]  in perl[5654e7ec1000+1a1000]
[ 5432.660131]  in perl[55b15d086000+1a1000]
[ 5432.660133] Code: 83 f8 05 0f 87 cf 00 00 00 0f b7 6b 22 66 81 fd 00 04 77 64 01 ed 8d 7d 05 48 63 ff 48 c1 e7 03 be 01 00 00 00 e8 4e ef ff ff <66> 89 68 22 48 89 c3 66 89 68 24 4c 89 68 08 49 8b 45 00 48 89 03
[ 5432.660142] Code: 83 f8 05 0f 87 cf 00 00 00 0f b7 6b 22 66 81 fd 00 04 77 64 01 ed 8d 7d 05 48 63 ff 48 c1 e7 03 be 01 00 00 00 e8 4e ef ff ff <66> 89 68 22 48 89 c3 66 89 68 24 4c 89 68 08 49 8b 45 00 48 89 03
[ 5432.660221] sleep[408436]: segfault at 0 ip 00007f18c67150b2 sp 00007ffdaf402820 error 4 in ld-linux-x86-64.so.2[7f18c66fa000+2a000]
[ 5432.660248] Code: 00 00 00 00 00 0f 1f 00 41 55 48 8d 05 50 1e 01 00 49 89 f5 49 89 c9 41 54 49 89 d4 48 89 c2 48 81 ec 18 04 00 00 85 ff 75 53 <41> 80 7d 00 00 48 8d 0d 2b 1e 01 00 4c 8d 05 d4 11 01 00 4c 0f 44
[ 5432.660417] Core dump to |/usr/share/apport/apport pipe failed
[ 5432.660480] Core dump to |/usr/share/apport/apport pipe failed
[ 5432.660543] Core dump to |/usr/share/apport/apport pipe failed
[ 5432.660593] perl[408406]: segfault at 22 ip 000055d5887c3cc2 sp 00007ffcf1af5220 error 6 in perl[55d5887c1000+1a1000]
[ 5432.660629] Code: 83 f8 05 0f 87 cf 00 00 00 0f b7 6b 22 66 81 fd 00 04 77 64 01 ed 8d 7d 05 48 63 ff 48 c1 e7 03 be 01 00 00 00 e8 4e ef ff ff <66> 89 68 22 48 89 c3 66 89 68 24 4c 89 68 08 49 8b 45 00 48 89 03
[ 5432.660888] Core dump to |/usr/share/apport/apport pipe failed
[ 5432.661682] perl[408391]: segfault at 22 ip 00005645d25a8cc2 sp 00007ffc836eb8b0 error 6 in perl[5645d25a6000+1a1000]
[ 5432.661718] Code: 83 f8 05 0f 87 cf 00 00 00 0f b7 6b 22 66 81 fd 00 04 77 64 01 ed 8d 7d 05 48 63 ff 48 c1 e7 03 be 01 00 00 00 e8 4e ef ff ff <66> 89 68 22 48 89 c3 66 89 68 24 4c 89 68 08 49 8b 45 00 48 89 03
[ 5432.661969] Core dump to |/usr/share/apport/apport pipe failed
[ 5433.228271] perl[408513]: segfault at 22 ip 000055bc88f1bcc2 sp 00007ffc31bb1ab0 error 6 in perl[55bc88f19000+1a1000]
[ 5433.228302] Code: 83 f8 05 0f 87 cf 00 00 00 0f b7 6b 22 66 81 fd 00 04 77 64 01 ed 8d 7d 05 48 63 ff 48 c1 e7 03 be 01 00 00 00 e8 4e ef ff ff <66> 89 68 22 48 89 c3 66 89 68 24 4c 89 68 08 49 8b 45 00 48 89 03
[ 5433.306971] perl[408642]: segfault at 22 ip 000055e76e66dcc2 sp 00007ffd37469c20 error 6 in perl[55e76e66b000+1a1000]
[ 5433.306999] Code: 83 f8 05 0f 87 cf 00 00 00 0f b7 6b 22 66 81 fd 00 04 77 64 01 ed 8d 7d 05 48 63 ff 48 c1 e7 03 be 01 00 00 00 e8 4e ef ff ff <66> 89 68 22 48 89 c3 66 89 68 24 4c 89 68 08 49 8b 45 00 48 89 03
[ 5433.307203] Core dump to |/usr/share/apport/apport pipe failed
[ 5433.820922] perl[408816]: segfault at 20 ip 0000557b90fb3463 sp 00007ffcd78bb6f0 error 4 in perl[557b90f88000+1a1000]
[ 5433.820953] Code: 89 df e8 60 9a 0e 00 48 8b 83 e0 00 00 00 48 8b 40 10 48 8b 13 48 85 c0 0f 85 79 ff ff ff e8 44 fc 06 00 48 8b 83 e0 00 00 00 <83> 78 20 00 79 2d 83 7b 30 00 7f 1b 48 8b bb f8 02 00 00 48 83 3f
[ 5433.821219] Core dump to |/usr/share/apport/apport pipe failed
```

(How can `sleep` of all programs segfault?!)

I have even now and then experienced that it takes down other programs on the machine.

Unfortunately the program to generate the race condition is quite big: (https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/parallel.git/tree/testsuite/tests-to-run/parallel-local-30s.sh) and I cannot make it much smaller without the race condition disappearing.

The test spawns in total more than 10000 communicating `perl` processes + ordinary shell programs (`sleep`, `sort`, `md5sum`, `bash`, `paste`, `wc`).

I have tested that this problem can be reproduced on my laptop and my 512GB server (so it is not caused by, say, bad RAM, overheating or out-of-memory).

How do I debug this and make this into a decent bug report for the relevant people? (And who are the relevant people? If both `perl` and `sleep` segfault, maybe we are taking a race condition in the kernel? Or in bash? Or libc?)

*Edit*

I installed FreeBSD12 (Vagrant). And the test runs flawlessly in FreeBSD12. This makes me think the kernel is to blame. It might also be that Vagrant somehow makes FreeBSD12 not fail.

Both the laptop and server runs Ubuntu22.04, so next is to try running a different kernel. Maybe Debian or CentOS. Also I should try if Ubuntu22.04 fails on Vagrant.

Works: FreeBSD12(Vagrant), Centos8(Vagrant), Ubuntu20.04(Vagrant), Ubuntu22.04(laptop t), Ubuntu22.10(Vagrant).

Fails: Ubuntu22.04(laptop a, server r).

I might have found the culprit:

```
echo 2 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

If I do this:

```
echo 0 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

the race condition disappears on server r.

But why on earth would that cause these errors?

*Edit*

Marcus suggests it may have to do with memory allocation, and when I have seen other processes die during the run, it is often with "xmalloc: cannot allocate **small number** bytes".

How do we test if this theory is correct?

Comment: What an excellent problem!

Comment: There's actually quite a corpus on *automatic test case reduction*, but it's mainly targeting compiler bugs (i e., It's mostly software that understands enough of a programming language to selectively remove parts of a program until it finds the smallest program that still makes the compiler crash or produce invalid code)

Comment: Man that sleep segfault is scary

Comment: Wait would it be possible that actually memory allocations fail the moment you accessed malloc'ed / sbrk'ed memory the first time? And the aspect that you're running many processes in parallel is the triggering factor because something in the system can't keep up with defragmenting some unused page table, so that the kernel wrongly assumes you run out of memory?

Comment: @MarcusMüller How come it works if I disable overcommit_memory? How come it fails on server r which has 500 GB free memory? How can we test if your theory is correct? Will there be indications in, say, /proc/slapinfo? There are indications that supports your theory, though: I have also seen errors like "xmalloc: cannot alloc xx bytes".

Comment: so many questions! 1. how come disabling helps: maybe in that mode, an otherwise failing malloc simply forces a consolidation of the free table pages / queue? 2. why fail on system with much free memory: the memory might be ultra fragmented from a lot of processes starting, malloc'ing, using, then free'ing/process ending. At 500 GB it would sound suprising, though, I agree. I'd feel more comfortable if we could actually see what leads to the segfaults. 3. THAT is the all-winning question, isn't it. I bet there's BPF-usable probes/hooks one could use to get both stats or even a backtrace 1/2

Comment: for whenever different kinds of segfaults are raised – after all, memory protection errors are always handled by the kernel first, and only if they're actual errors (and not just, say, accessing memory that has not yet been actually allocated or needs to be fetched from swap space) it would send the signal to the process/kill it. 2/2

Comment: I found a snippet of code at https://www.lug-erding.de/blog/2020-05-15-linux-und-overcommit_memory.html (page in german, code in C), which allocates up to 100G memory. Try this with different overcommit settings and you might get the idea (0 and 1 always get 100G, 2 doesn't). On my system here setting overcommit to 2 i coldn't even execute the binary (too much memory fragmentation probably). The latter might be the reason why it even fails on a 500G machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `ps aux` run during the test reveals lines like:

```
tange    1471203  0.0  0.0 264173920 3776 pts/1  T    20:54   0:00 sort --buffer-size=50% -k3r
```

264173920 is 50% of 500 GB, and there are 20 of those.

meminfo says:

```
$ grep Committ /proc/meminfo
Committed_AS:   5291525876 kB
```

So my assumption that 500GB would be enough was wrong.

Removing `--buffer-size=50%` gives:

```
$ grep Committ /proc/meminfo
Committed_AS:   45391448 kB
```

and the test completes with no problem with /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory=2.

All in all this explains most of the situation: running `sort --buffer-size=50%` gobbles up a lot of (virtual) memory and since overcommit_memory=2 requires the virtual memory to be available, there is no more memory available to other processes.

With overcommit_memory=0 the memory does not need to be available and thus nothing fails (since only a tiny amount of the memory is ever used).

I can now provoke the issue with:

```
parallel '(seq {};sleep 10) | sort --buffer-size=50%' ::: {1..20}
```

What annoys me, though, is why `sort` is not complaining `sort: memory exhausted` or showing up in `dmesg`. This would have guided me much quicker towards the error.